# La concordancia en singular de "gente" en oraciones separadas

Tags: plurales, concordancia-gramatical, concordancia-verbal

Según indica el *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* con respecto a la concordancia de los sustantivos singulares con sentido plural:

> La concordancia en plural sí es admisible cuando se pasa de una
> oración a otra, pues en ese caso al segundo verbo le corresponde, en
> realidad, un sujeto plural tácito: «La gente se acercaba y en cuanto
> veían la escena chillaban» (Llongueras Llongueras [Esp. 2001]);

Lógicamente, eso nos hace pensar que, bajo tales circunstancias, son aceptables ambas concordancias, ya que si no fuera así, la formas plurales no serían admisibles sino obligatorias. No obstante, parece que la concordancia en plural está más extendida, en tal grado que se inmiscuye en frases en las que, según las autoridades lingüísticas, su uso es incorrecto. Por ejemplo, "esta gente siempre piensan [algo]".

Eso me lleva a preguntar si se observa la concordancia en singular en este tipo de oraciones, es decir, cuando el sujeto de la primera oración es "gente" o algo similar, mientras que la segunda lo tiene como sujeto implícito. He aquí dos ejemplos:

> La gente es muy optimista por [cosas]. Cree que....

> A: Esta gente no es de fiar.
>
> B: De acuerdo. Está trabajando a escondidas para socavar el proyecto.

Comment: Concuerdo con la concordancia. Sólo agregar que en el ámbito literario tambien se usa gentes y en ese caso cuando alude a más de una persona, entonces vale "estas gentes siempre piensan igual", no así cuando alude a una sola "Él era un tipo de gente que siempre pensaba igual/Él era una gente..". Lo otro es que me suena extraño 'de confiar', es 'de confianza' o 'de fiar'.

Comment: @cocteau - A lo mejor "no es de fiar" suena más natural y es más común, pero se pueden encontrar diverso ejemplos de "no es de confiar" así que no creo que sea necesario editar la pregunta.

Comment: Dejará de confiar es lógico, pero no que una persona 'no es de confiar', se dice 'no es de confianza', no es como para+verbo=confiar en ella también .

Comment: Lo he cambiado porque seguramente es más natural así, pero es fácil encontrar ejemplos de "no ser de confiar" en libros o en periódicos, por no decir en Internet.

Comment: de confianza=2. loc. adj. Dicho de una persona: En quien se puede confiar; de fiar = 1. loc. adj. Digno de confianza; I was never one to trust=Nunca fui de fiar; "...would stop trusting in=dejará de confiar en".

Comment: Claro, no dudo de que todas esas locuciones también son correctas. Solo digo que hay muchos ejemplos de la frase "de confiar" que no parecen ser errores.

Comment: P. ej. en *Mi último crimen* de Fernando Aybar Sobre-Casas, un personaje dice que "tú no eres de confiar".

Comment: Tal vez es algo regional, algo más de centroámerica o de la comunidad hispana en usa.

Comment: También lo dice una canción colombiana, pero de verdad que me suena extrañisimo.

Answer (score 1):

Está claro que "gente" es un sustantivo colectivo y que, por lo tanto, concuerda con el verbo en singular.

El cambio de número en el ejemplo que cita el DPD funciona porque no se trata de verbos coordinados en un predicado compuesto que comparten el mismo sujeto (*La gente se acercaba y chillaba*), sino que estamos en presencia de proposiciones coordinadas, cada una con su sujeto, que aunque se repita en lo semántico es gramaticalmente diferente.

Así como puede cambiar el número entre proposiciones coordinadas, lo mismo puede ocurrir entre distintas oraciones. Se tenderá a mantener el singular si el sustantivo colectivo se concibe como una unidad, mientras que el plural aparecerá si se piensa en los individuos que forman el conjunto.

Comment: Entonces ¿crees que una oración como las que que escribí sería correcta, a pesar de que parecen ser poco comunes?

Comment: @Obie2.0 La primera me parece perfecta. En la segunda hubiera usado definitivamente el plural, tal vez porque está más alejada: De acuerdo. Están trabajando a escondidas...